# Ubuntu 21.04 TP-Link Archer T2U Plus (RTL8821AU] driver

Tags: wireless, 21.04

I have installed Ubuntu with dualboot alongside Windows. Everything is working, but I can't connect to wifi. I think Ubuntu didn't download my WiFi adapter's driver. How can I download it? Thanks.

The output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link Archer T2U PLUS [RTL8821AU]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:2d43 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:64ab Microdia Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2/50
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0043 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please check with `lspci` (for internal) or `lsusb` (for USB, external). One of them will identify your hardware. The please edit the question to add that information. Dual boot is immaterial for this case except if you still have Fast Startup enabled in Windows. Disabling it is a MUST for dual-booting.

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong my wifi adpter is Archer T2U Plus (RTL8821AU). And i added 'lsusb' s output.

Comment: Or use this got instead as it seems to have a newer driver version: https://github.com/morrownr/8821au

Comment: Thanks! Its now working.